# wordpress wp-includes prevent directory access

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, fatal-error

I have checked many wp sites recently and they allow to access the file from the include folder and they show error message on it

Path is

```
wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-background-position-control.php
```

**Error message**

```
Fatal error: Class 'WP_Customize_Control' not found in /home4/pcc/public_html/project/autosite/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-background-position-control.php on line 1
```

Ideally it should not be accessible directly

I have used this in my htaccess but still same error

```
Options All -Indexes
```

- Also they are crawling in google.

Answer (score 0):

The de-index job will not work because it's a well-known file in all WordPress installation and `Options -Indexes` did not prevent users to access this.

Place a .htaccess file in **wp-includes** folder with below content. It's will return 403 status code when someone try to access .php file in **wp-includes** folder and its subfolders.

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```